# Import text file to new sheet, do some operations, then close the sheet

Tags: vba, excel, import, text-files

I have a problem that I need help to solve. I want to import a text file to a new temporary sheet, find some data, put them in my current sheet and then close the new temporary sheet. Is this possible and how do I do this?

Comment: Can you provide an example of how the data is presented in the text file, and what exactly you want to do with it?

Comment: That is something I dont know. At the moment I just need to know how to Open a new sheet, Import a text file and then Close the sheet again and go back to the sheet I started with.

Comment: To open a new sheet is easy, I use Sheets.Add.Name = "Test". But the problem seems to be the part where I want to close it and go back to my original sheet.

Comment: To import a text file to a worksheet i'd use a querytable, you can get some suitable code, or a starting point, from the macro recorder. Just be sure to close the connection once you're done.

Answer (score 1):

To create a new Worksheet, then remove it:

---

```
Option Explicit

Sub openWorkSheet()
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets.Add(, ThisWorkbook.ActiveSheet)
End Sub

Sub closeWorkSheet(ByRef ws As Worksheet)
    If Not ws Is Nothing Then
        With Application
            .DisplayAlerts = False
            ws.Delete
            .DisplayAlerts = True
        End With
    End If
End Sub
```

---

To open a text file, read its contents and find specific strings:

---

```
Public Sub searchFile(ByVal filePathAndName As String)

    Const TYPICAL_START = "FIRST search string"
    Const TYPICAL_END = "LAST search string"

    Dim fso As Object
    Dim searchedFile As Object
    Dim fullFile As String
    Dim foundStart As Long
    Dim foundEnd As Long
    Dim resultArr() As String
    Dim i As Long

    Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
    Set searchedFile = fso.OpenTextFile(filePathAndName)

    fullFile = searchedFile.ReadAll 'read entire file

    i = 1
    foundStart = 1
    foundStart = InStr(foundStart, fullFile, TYPICAL_START, vbTextCompare)

    If foundStart > 0 Then

        foundEnd = InStr(foundStart, fullFile, TYPICAL_END, vbTextCompare)

        While foundStart > 0 And foundEnd > 0
            ReDim Preserve resultArr(i)
            resultArr(i) = Mid(fullFile, foundStart, foundEnd - foundStart + 1)
            foundStart = InStr(foundStart + 1, fullFile, TYPICAL_START, vbTextCompare)
            If foundStart > 0 Then foundEnd = InStr(foundStart, fullFile, TYPICAL_END)
            i = i + 1
        Wend
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you! openWorkSheet and closeWorkSheet works just fine. I have not tried searchFile yet but i tried this below. And it imports the text file I  want but for some reason I cant make any calculations. Do you know why?

Comment: Sub Import()
       Dim DestBook As Workbook, SourceBook As Workbook
       Dim DestCell As Range
       Dim RetVal As Boolean

       Set DestBook = ActiveWorkbook
       Set DestCell = ActiveCell

       RetVal = Application.Dialogs(xlDialogOpen).Show("*.txt", , True)

       If RetVal = False Then Exit Sub

       Set SourceBook = ActiveWorkbook

       Range(Range("A1"), Range("A1").SpecialCells(xlLastCell)).Copy

       DestBook.Activate
       DestCell.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlValues
       
       SourceBook.Close False
End Sub

Comment: For the Sub in your comments you should open a new question. Let me know if the answer provided you with enough details for the original post

Answer (score 0):

So now it shold work. This is the sub that does not want to work.

Sub Import()

```
   Dim DestBook As Workbook, SourceBook As Workbook
   Dim DestCell As Range
   Dim RetVal As Boolean

   ' Set object variables for the active book and active cell.
   Set DestBook = ActiveWorkbook
   Set DestCell = ActiveCell

   ' Show the Open dialog box.
   RetVal = Application.Dialogs(xlDialogOpen).Show("*.txt", , True)

   ' If Retval is false (Open dialog canceled), exit the procedure.
   If RetVal = False Then Exit Sub

   ' Set an object variable for the workbook containing the text file.
   Set SourceBook = ActiveWorkbook

   ' Copy the contents of the entire sheet containing the text file.
   Range(Range("A1"), Range("A1").SpecialCells(xlLastCell)).Copy

   ' Activate the destination workbook and paste special the values
   ' from the text file.
   DestBook.Activate
   DestCell.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlValues

   ' Close the book containing the text file.
   SourceBook.Close False
```

End Sub